# Non-standard integers?

Tags: logic, model-theory, nonstandard-analysis, nonstandard-models

**Edit:** Realized almost immediately that this was a stupid question - see comment below. Was about to delete it when an answer appeared that seems like saving...

Context: I just saw a presentation  of  a "senior homors thesis" consisting of more or less empty speculation on applications of non-standard analysis to number theory.

Actually I missed the talk, heard about it afterwards. The advisor didn't have any actual applications in mind, was just speculating on how  it might be that things like $\Bbb Z_p$ for an infinite prime $p$ could be interesting. Probably just as well I wasn't there, because I might have asked this:

**Q:** Before we can talk about infinite primes we need to know what an infinite integer is.  *Is* there a "standard" definition of the non-standard integers as a subset of the non-standard reals?

*My* non-standard reals tend to come from the Compactness Theorem in logic. So I'd know what a non-standard integer was if I had a first-order definition of $\Bbb Z$ as a subset of $\Bbb R$; I can't imagine how that would go. *Is* $\Bbb Z$ definable in the first-order theory of $\Bbb R$?

(Yes of course if we  want to do non-standard number theory we could just as well  start by applying the compactness theorem to the theory of $\Bbb Z$; that doesn't quite answer the question...)

Comment: Don't you like ultrapowers? Take an ultrapower ${}^*\Bbb R$ of copies of $\Bbb R$; then there is a copy ${}^*\Bbb Z$ of the corresponding ultrapower of $\Bbb Z$ within, as indeed there is ${}^*A\subseteq {}^*\Bbb R$ for any $A\subseteq\Bbb R$.

Comment: Duh, stupid question. Of course in that construction we start with the theory of $\Bbb R$ in a large language, including a predicate for "is an integer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An application of $Z_p$ for infinite $p$ was given by Alexei Belov in the context of the Jacobian conjecture in algebraic geometry.  See https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0512171 and later papers.

Answer (score 2):

The integers, as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, cannot be defined in the first-order language of ordered fields: i.e. using the constants, (partial) operations, and relation $0,1,+,-,\cdot,{}^{-1},\leq$.

This fact arises from the theory of [real closed fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field), which has the notable feature of being *complete*.

Gödel's incompleteness theorem therefore proves that one cannot identify the integers, because that would let you reproduce Peano arithmetic. However, if I recall correctly, more can be said:

- the only subsets that *can* be so defined are finite unions of intervals
- of those, the only ones that can be defined without parameters are those where the intervals have algebraic (or infinite) endpoints

---

However, the (IMO) more generally useful formulation of nonstandard analysis doesn't take a theory of *real numbers* as the starting point — it takes a theory of *sets*.

In particular, one uses their favorite means to obtain an elementary extension of a [superstructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe_(mathematics)) which knows about all of the sets one would use in the course of real analysis.

In the way I know to carry out construction, $\mathbb{Z}$ is a *constant symbol* of this theory, so its trivial to identify it.

Comment: Actually, as I recalled a minute after posting this, it's probably more accurate to say it starts with the theorey of $\Bbb R$, but in a huge language, including, for  each $S\subset \Bbb R$, a predicate $p_S(x)$ with $p_S(x)$ part of the theory if and only if $x\in S$.